# Is an instance of a class kept in memory if I don't assign it?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it kept allocated in memory after the method is called?

```
private void AnyMethod()
{
  new AnotherClass().AnotherMethod();
}
```

Comment: This is valid C# code..... :D

Comment: @fubo and dotctor: Without 'void' it's still valid code. That's called a constructor. A private one, in this case.

Comment: @L-Three, You are right. Removed the comment

Comment: @L-Three Does it makes any difference according the question?

Comment: Actually my point is 'new AnotherClass().AnotherMethod();' here

Comment: I have seem some, if not a lot, of calls like this, and I was wondering if that won't be flooding the memory with garbage

Comment: It does, and it trashed it afterwards. Not very performance effective, but it works. @FabricioSomini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what is inside the constructor and that method, but usually it isn't.

When the method call ends, the instantiated class doesn't have any references any more, so it can be garbage collected whenever the GC comes around, which may vary given GC settings and memory pressure.

It is possible though that you do something like this in your constructor or method, which will prevent the instance to go out of scope:

```
SomeExternalClass.SomeInstance = this;
```

Comment: It may also very well be collected *before* the method ends - as long as `this` is no longer used in the method, it may be collected at any time. I'd guess it's also possible for `this` to be collected *before* the method is called if the compiler can decide this is safe - e.g. when the method is inlined.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that, so thanks for completing my answer :) @Luaan

Answer (score 3):

After the method is called, the instance on which this method was called falls out of scope (because it has no longer any references pointing to it), so it is eligible to garbage collection. So this instance will be kept in memory until the actual garbage collection occurs. The exact timing when this garbage collection will occur will of course depend on many properties of the runtime, like memory usage, ...

Comment: What if the reference for already constructed `AnotherClass` has been kept in a static variable inside it's constructor?

Comment: Then this instance will be kept in memory obviously, but I don't think that that's what the OP is asking. As long as there are references to a variable, it will not be eligible for garbage collection and all resources associated with it will be kept.

Comment: No, that is not possible since the `this` 'variable' is always within the method scope. @Joey

Comment: @Joey, I am really not that much familiar with the internals of the CLR to say if the instance will be eligible to garbage collection before the method completes if this method doesn't reference any instance resources of the class. I very much doubt it because the `this` reference always exists during an instance method execution. I have never heard of similar optimization, but I am not saying that it is not possible. On the other hand if the method was static then you wouldn't have needed an instance of `AnotherClass` in order to call it in the first place.

Comment: And you can't call a static method on an instance, right? @DarinDimitrov

Comment: @PatrickHofman, that's right. This is the reason why I mentioned in my previous comment that you wouldn't need an instance of the class if the method was static.

Comment: Okay, it was 'don't need' vs. 'can't have'.